# Difference between two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, diff

I have two vectors:

```
a <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9)
b <- c(2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2)
```

I want to find the numbers in the second vector, which are not in the  first vector:

```
dif <- c(2, 6, 8)
```

I've tried many different approaches (such as merge, different types of joins (dplyr package), setdiff, compare (compare package)), but I still can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(b,a)
#[1] 2 6 8
```

Comment: `setdiff(1:3,2:4)` results: > 1

Comment: for me expecte is 1 and 4

Comment: @stakowerflol  `setdiff` gives the the difference of the 1st compared to the second.  If you want both, then you may need a union and setdiff

Answer (score 19):

An alternative way, instead of `setdiff` (which is probably preferrable), is to use `%in%`

```
unique(b[! b %in% a])
#[1] 2 6 8
```

Comment: Hi @nico, the `unique(b[! b %in% a]` works great for this example. But, please, do you see any reason why I got `numeric(0)` answer when changing vectors `a = c(4,2,3)` and `b = c(2,3)`? does not make sense to me.



unique(b[!b %in% a])

Comment: @maycca Your output is right. It shows the elements that are in b and not in a, which is an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

The exact question has been answered but if someone wants to find all elements not shared between two lists then this is the answer:

```
union(setdiff(a,b), setdiff(b,a))
```

Here 'a' and 'b' could be something like

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(4,5,6,7,8)
```